# Replacing All UIButton Touch Events With Throttle

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to globally prevent the user from double tapping a button.  As a proof of concept I started to override the addTarget method of UI button and replaced the original call with a throttled call using RxSwift:

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

public extension UIButton {

    override open func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents) {

        guard controlEvents == UIControlEvents.touchUpInside,
              let viewController = target as? UIViewController
        else
        {
            super.addTarget(target, action: action, for: controlEvents)
            return
        }

        self.rx
            .tap
            .throttle(3,
                      latest: false,
                      scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe({ _ in
                viewController.perform(action)
            })
    }
}
```

When calling this code I get a Bad Access error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

I'm pretty new to Swift, so any guidance on where to start troubleshooting or alternate suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple:

> [Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

A better solution would be to make a new method, instead of trying to override the current one, and do a global find and replace to point to the new method.

Since you are bringing RxSwift into your project, why not use it?

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIButton {
    public var safeTap: ControlEvent<Void> {
        return ControlEvent.init(events: tap.throttle(3, latest: false, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance))
    }
}
```

Comment: Call stack isn't large.  Isn't addTarget just called when setting up the binding (wiring up the button to code)?

Comment: The main reason I didn't create a new method was because I didn't want to have to update the existing code...just have it centrally adjusted/maintained.  Is there really no way to do this globally?

Comment: I pasted your code into an app and ran it. I'm seeing inconsistent results so I looked into it and changed my answer. RxSwift works by setting up a binding for itself. It has to wire up the button code too and uses `addTarget(_action:for:)` to do that. Another option would be to make a UIButton subclass and do a global find and replace that. Either way, you need to update the existing code.